# i have user adding form, each user has delete button. how can i make it delete it's user?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, function, components

user.model.ts  // interface for user

```
export interface User {
    id:number,
    firstName:string,
    lastName:string,
    eMail:string
}
```

form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../interfaces/user.model';

@Component({
  ***
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  idNumber: number = 0;
  userInfo: User[] = [];
  constructor() { }

  addUser(firstname: HTMLInputElement, lastname: HTMLInputElement, email: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.idNumber += 1;
    this.userInfo.push({ id: this.idNumber, firstName: firstname.value, lastName: lastname.value, eMail: email.value });
    console.log(this.userInfo)
    ***
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

table.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 ***
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() users:any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

table.component.html
there is a delete button for each user I add. I want them to delete users which belong to them. is it possible to pass the user index?

```
<table class="ui celled table">
    <thead>
       ***
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.eMail}}</td>
            <td style="width: 40px;" ><button class="delButton"><i class="times icon"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It is better to use random number for each component.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
<table class="ui celled table">
<thead>
   ***
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users;let i = index">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.eMail}}</td>
        <td style="width: 40px;" ><button class="delButton" (click)="deleteUser(i)"><i class="times icon"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And inside the table.component.ts file add the following function

```
deleteUser(index: number) { this.users.splice(index, 1); }
```